# Delphi: Show/Hide Glyph from a TBitbtn

Tags: delphi, button, glyph

I would like to hide or show the glyph from a `bitbtn` after the same button is pressed.

Example: I have on a form with a 'Back' button and a 'Next' button. Both have a glyph with arrows. After the 'Next' button is pressed it's transforming in 'Finish' button without a glyph. Similar if the 'Back' button is pressed, the 'Finish' button is becoming 'Next' button with the arrow glyph. Finish button have no icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glyph is of type TBitmap. In order to hide the glyph, assign Nil to it:

```
MyButton.Glyph := Nil;
```

In order to show a glyph, you need a TBitmap object with the image and assign it to Glyph:

```
MyButton.Glyph := MyBitmap;
```

Comment: bitmap is already loaded. that was the point to hide it without to remove it.

Comment: @REALSOFO: You can't. To hide it you need to remove it. There is no visible property for the glyph on a TBitBtn.

Comment: I would be tempted to just switch out two controls at the same position, at runtime, make one visible, then the other. Much less chance of bad things happening.

Comment: It is a shame that that `TBitBtn.NumGlyphs` property cannot be set to 0, that would have probably solved the problem, too.  But alas, values < 1 are ignored.

Comment: I thought so, that glyph can not be hidden. So, switch between two controls will remain the solution. Anyhow, thank you guys!

Comment: An update to this. Assigning "nil" to the glyph worked up through Delphi 10.4. When we tried in Delphi 10.4.2, we noticed some things:

 1. The glyphs have been updated.
 2. When you assign a "Kind", the glyph property is no longer assigned anything.
 3. Assigning "nil" no longer gets rid of the glyph in 10.4.2 or 11.1.

Basically, it looks like the display of a glyph when a Kind is assigned is now completely internalized. I have submitted a ticket to Embarcadero about this and am awaiting a response.

Comment: An update to my previous update. A developer at Embarcadero responded to me. We worked out a potential solution so that, when you assign "nil" to the glyph property, the glyph on the TBitBtn will be gone. This change will likely go into effect when 11.1 Update 3 is released (won't be in Update 2).